# Computing which side of a line a point is

Tags: math, geometry, line, point

I looked at this question : [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461453/determine-which-side-of-a-line-a-point-lies)

I tried proving the accepted answer equation with trigonometry :[image]

AB is the line, C is the point.

In the accepted answer of the above question, if the difference in equation is 0, then points are collinear, so in the above image, it proves it correct as theta is same, so far so good.

Then in the image below, c lies on right of line :[image]

the fi angle is less than theta so the difference is positive. So in my program if I take > 0 as condition for the point on right, then the difference should always be greater than 0 if point is on right.

But my next figure shows that the even if the point is on right of the line, the difference can be negative :[image]

In figure 3, even though the point is on right of the line, fi is greater than theta, so the diffrence is negative.

In accepted answer, if I take positive difference for point on right side, then the above case will give wrong results.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Putting it as a ratio like that is an interesting twist, but most everyone else will be thinking directly in terms of cross products and the parallelogram formed by B-A and C-A.  But never mind; this is math and therefore not ideal for SO.  Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ratios are actually tan of your angles.

But you do it wrong:

First, you need to be consistent in your angle - if you start with negative Ox direction, then C then A in the first case, then you should do the same in the second case. 
So instead of theta you need 180-theta.

Second, the tan function is not increasing when it goes from < 90 to > 90 (it is in fact discontinuous). Thus if you compare fi (which is < 90) with 180-theta (which is > 90) you can't say that the tan of the first is less than tan of the second. It can be either way.