# Varying results while finding the position of the point wrt a line

Tags: matlab, geometry, line, point

This is in reference to - [Determine which side of a line a point lies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461453/determine-which-side-of-a-line-a-point-lies)

This an observation - I am trying to count points meeting my criteria using two of the above mentioned techniques i.e. the determinant using two reference points and third point to compare. Also alternatively I am using the slope method. Here, i already have a reference angle, one point fixed, and other varying points which need to be checked. so basically I am checking the angle which the lines are making with the horizontal.

I am getting different results, with the determinant, the result is approximately 3% more. Basically, more points are considered.

Any idea why this might be happening. Is this error in any way related to rounding off, in case of this being related to a rounding off error, which method is reliable? I am using tand() in matlab to compute the angles and then compare, and det() function to find the value of the determinant.

The code when comparing angles is as shown below

```
angle = E(l);
    while i+1 < len_y                       % Y co-ordinates
        while j+1 < len_x                   % X co-ordinates [The manner of saving the 2D matrix and the analysis are both in sync.]
            if z_1(i,j) <= z_1(i,j+1)       % check for the first peak
                j = j + 1;
            else z_1(i,j) > z_1(i,j+1);     % this is the first peak, where we set up the line
                while j+1 < len_x           % set up a line using the angle
                    z0 = z_1(i,j);          % this is the first point of the line
                    x0 = X(j);              
                        x1 = x0 + 10;           % problem solved.
                z1 = z0  - (tand(E(l)) * (x1 - x0)); % this is to setup the line to compare is a point is below or above it
                    j = j + 1;
                    trial_angle = atand((z0 - z_1(j))/(X(j) - x0));

                    while trial_angle > E(l) & j < len_x;         % check the first point of intersection of the line
                        j = j + 1;
                        trial_angle = atand((z0 - z_1(j))/(X(j) - x0));

                    end % end of points which are not in contact
```

I am using MATLAB 2012 and Win7 64 bit

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

thedorkknight

Comment: Some of your code will be helpful

Comment: I don't see `det` anywhere in your code (which of course isn't particularly helpful since it can't be run). I'd suggest that you find a specific point for which the two methods return a different result and investigate further.

Comment: A vectorized anonymous function for determining the side of a line that a point falls on via the determinant: `linesidedet=@(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)sign((x2-x1)*(y3(:)-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x3(:)-x1));`. Demo for a diagonal Y=X line and 10,000 normally distributed points: `side=linesidedet(0,0,1,1,randn(1e4,1),randn(1e4,1));nnz(side==1)`.