# Testing if the points of a polygon are listed clockwise or anti-clockwise

Tags: c#, trigonometry

Given a list of x,y co-ordinates for a polygon, how can I tell if those points are listed clockwise, or anticlockwise?

Background - I'm trying to test if a drone has breached a geo-fence. I have the x,y co-ordinates of the drone, and I have the x,y co-ordinates of each corner of the geo-fence.

I'm following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668659/calculate-on-which-side-of-a-line-a-point-is) post about how to determine if a point is to the left or right of a line. It follows that if a point is to the right of *every* side of a polygon then that point must be within that polygon. However, to get this work, I need make sure that I know the direction (clockwise or anti-clockwise) that those points are list in.

Consider these three points....
p0(1,1)
p1(2,6)
p2(4,1)
I've listed them in a clockwise fashion, if my drone is to the right of the line p0-p1, and to the right of p1-p2, and the right of p2-p0, then the drone within the geofence. But this is only true if the points are listed clockwise. How do I check this is true?

Comment: An additional complication is that on Earth, any polygon is a *bisection*, so you would have to clarify which one of the two polygons you mean. (What sounds like sophistry becomes relevant if you want to prevent your drone e.g. to enter the southern hemisphere.)