# Polygons collision detection silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, collision-detection, game-physics

This is not a generic question on collision detection, so please read it till the end.

In my wp7 game, i represent all my objects as rectangles, and use the the Intersect() method to check for collisions between 2 rectangles, which works great.

I was thinking of enhancing the accuracy by drawing the objects as polygons instead of rectangles.

Is there a built in api such as the Rect.Intersect() that works for Polygons ?

More generic question: Is there a better approach other than the Rect.Intersect() one which utilizes .net api's and **does not** involve implementing collision detection algorithms?

Comment: Oh crap, I made the assumption you were using xna. Is that the case or no?

Comment: no i'm using silverlight not xna 
i thought that was obvious from the tag and question header :)

Comment: Sorry bout the mix up. I've played alot with xna and that is a fairly common type of question. Just kinda went with the gut reaction lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no baked in equivalent for polygons collision detection in silverlight. There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119451/how-to-tell-if-a-line-intersects-a-polygon-in-c). But there is a [Polygon Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) JIC you didn't already know