# Checking if a CGRect is intersected by a line

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect, cgpoint

`start` and `end` are both `CGPoint`s. I've drawn an auxiliary line between them to help model the situation. I want to be able to test if an object (`UIImageView` --> `[imageView frame]` aka `CGRect`) is intersected by that line.

[image: Just a diagram to help explain my question :)]

Comment: Take a look at this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755819/determine-if-line-intersects-cgrect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203760/how-to-check-if-line-segment-intersects-a-rectangle