# How do I make something happen when a UIImageView hits certain points on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` that the user can drag around. I want something to happen when it hits (gets dragged over) certain points on the screen (all the points from `x: 0 y: 0` to `x: 0 y: 100`).

This is the code I currently use:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.first as! UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    imageView.center = location
}

func pointDetection() {
    if location == CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100) {
        println("1 Point!")
    } else {
        println("0 Points")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in your question *"(all the points from `x: 0 y: 0` to `x: 0 y: 100`)"* but your `if` statement is only `true` for one specific point, `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)`.

Change it to something like this:

```
if location.y >= 0.0 && location.y <= 100.0 {
    println("1 Point!")
} else {
    println("0 Points")
}
```

I don't see where you're calling your `pointDetection()` function either. Add it to `touchesMoved`.

Comment: Oops yeah you're right, but i still get no reaction.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I've literately been looking everywhere on how to do this and it just worked. I just started learning swift so this was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the line instead point? Just every time check if previous and new point located on opposite sides of your line:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y, nowPoint.x + prevPoint.x, nowPoint.y + prevPoint.y);
    // then check if line intersects a rectangle
}
```

[Here is example of intersects function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17762050/2756897)

Comment: This question is in Swift, your answer is in Objective-C.

Comment: Can you do it for me? Because i dont know Objective-C