# A special case of intersection of line and rectrangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

How to check **if a line intersects a rectangle** has been frequently asked, e.g.,[How to know if a line intersects a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514366/how-to-know-if-a-line-intersects-a-rectangle) . The basic idea of solution is to check if

- any of the four line segments of the rectangle intersects this line
- this rectangle contains both start and end points of this line

But this method fails to handle a special case, and this case should not be considered as an intersection in my application:

[image]

Here, the line passes the corner point while the whole MBR lies in one side of this line. So, how to check this special case?

Comment: You don't tell us if this is considered an intersection or not.

Comment: such case is not considered as an intersection @YvesDaoust

Comment: So seems enough to change comparison`r < 0` and similar ones  to `r<=0` and so on to exclude side ends.

Answer (score 1):

I designed a feasible solution to check this special case. This special case happens on when **whole MBR lies in the one side of the line**.

We need a helper method to get the position of a point:

```
# p is the query point, (a, b) is the line
def position(p, a, b):
    return np.sign((b.x - a.x) * (p.y - a.y) - (p.x - a.x) * (b.y - a.y))
```

Then we get all positions of four corners:

```
# left_bottom ... are corners
# (start, end) is the line
f = lambda m: position(m, start, end)
vf = np.vectorize(f)
positions = vf(np.array([left_bottom, right_bottom, left_top, right_top]))
```

The special case happens when one of position equals to 0, and all positions is either -1 or 1:

```
if len(np.where(positions == 0)) == 1 and abs(np.sum(positions)) == 3:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

If the coordinates are represented as floating-point reals, exact coincidence of a segment over a corner is rare and somewhat random, due to truncation errors. One can wonder what the benefit is to even worry about these "corner cases".

Depending on the application, dealing with a degenerate intersection (i.e. a single point instead of a segment) maybe more embarrassing than helpful.

More context is necessary to answer your question in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, we assume that the segment, denoted `OP`, starts from the origin. (If not, translate all points.)

A point of the segment `OP` is given by the vector expression

```
t.P
```

with `t` in `[0, 1]`.

Such a point belongs to the closed rectangle `[X0, X1] x [Y0, Y1]` when

```
X0 ≤ Px.t ≤ X1
Y0 ≤ Py.t ≤ Y1
```

To discuss these inequations, we have to distinguish nine cases depending on the signs of `Px` and `Py`.

Let us handle the case of two positives. Then we write

```
Py.X0 ≤ Px.Py.t ≤ Py.X1
Px.Y0 ≤ Px.Py.t ≤ Px.Y1
```

together with

```
0 ≤ Px.Py.t ≤ Px.Py
```

which expresses the limits of the segment.

Then the solution set is not empty under the condition

```
Max(Py.X0, Px.Y0, 0) ≤ Min(Py.X1, Px.Y1, Px.Py)
```

The other cases can be handled similarly. The computational cost is

```
6 initial subtractions
2 3-way sign tests
5 multiplications
5 comparisons
```

(when the initial comparisons conclude equality, the expressions simplify a little* and the cost is lower).

Note that this formulation avoids divisions, for efficiency. As said in my other answer, the relevance of `<` vs. `≤` is quite debatable (possibly handled with interval arithmetic).

---

*Let `Py=0`, then we write the inequations as

```
X0 ≤ Px.t ≤ X1
Y0 ≤    0 ≤ Y1
 0 ≤ Px.t ≤ Px
```

and the condition is

```
Max(X0, 0) ≤ Min(X1, Px) and Y0 ≤ 0 ≤ Y1.
```

And obviously, `Px=Py=0` is solved with

```
X0 ≤ 0 ≤ X1 and Y0 ≤ 0 ≤ Y1.
```